# dictionary group by substring of key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sum

In Python3, I have a dictionnary *{k = episode : value = count}* and I can't figure out how to group by substring of keys where values are summed.

input:

```
dict = {'S01E01': 27, 'S01E02': 27, 'S01E03': 32, 'S01E04': 36, 'S01E05': 35, 'S01E06': 31,
 'S02E01': 33, 'S02E02': 21, 'S02E03': 20, 'S02E04': 29, 'S02E05': 33, 'S02E06': 42}
```

Wanted ouput:

```
output_dict = {'S01': 188 , 'S02' : 178}
```

I've tried building an intermediary list of seasons and tried to use reduce & counter functions with no success.

```
List = ['S01', 'S02']
```

Also tried looking for any results in here but couldn't find anything. Wrong terminology probably. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict` comprehension:

```
 from itertools import groupby

 {key:sum(list(zip(*val))[1]) for key, val in groupby(d.items(), key = lambda x:x[0][:3])}
  Out: {'S01': 188, 'S02': 178}
```

Using the normal for loop first save your data as `d`. then `delete dict` since its an internal function ie `del dict`. Now you can run the following code

```
result = dict()

for key, val in d.items():
    var1 = key[:3]
    if not result.get(var1):
        result[var1] = 0
    result[var1]  += val
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Onyambu is probably the more pythonic way to solve this problem, but if you're looking for a more human readable solution that *fits this specific use case* then you can do something like this:

```
episodes = {'S01E01': 27, 'S01E02': 27, 'S01E03': 32, 'S01E04': 36, 'S01E05': 35, 'S01E06': 31,
 'S02E01': 33, 'S02E02': 21, 'S02E03': 20, 'S02E04': 29, 'S02E05': 33, 'S02E06': 42}

output = {}

for episode in episodes:
    season = episode[0:3] #Gets the first 3 characters
    if season not in output:
        output[season] = episodes[episode] 
    else:
        output[season] += episodes[episode]
print(output)
```

Comment: Indeed, much more logic expressed in these terms. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the subkey is only 3 characters long.

```
dic = {'S01E01': 27, 'S01E02': 27, 'S01E03': 32, 'S01E04': 36, 'S01E05': 35, 'S01E06': 31,
 'S02E01': 33, 'S02E02': 21, 'S02E03': 20, 'S02E04': 29, 'S02E05': 33, 'S02E06': 42}
```

First extract unique subkeys:

```
subkeys = set([key[:3] for key in dic.keys()])
```

Afterwards, use a dictionary comprehension to sum up values for each subkey.

```
out = {subkey: sum([value for key, value in dic.items() if subkey in key]) for subkey in subkeys}
```

Uglier one-liner:

```
out = {subkey[:3]: sum([value for key, value in dic.items() if subkey[:3] in key]) for subkey in dic.keys()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
data = {'S01E01': 27, 'S01E02': 27, 'S01E03': 32, 'S01E04': 36, 'S01E05': 35, 'S01E06': 31,
 'S02E01': 33, 'S02E02': 21, 'S02E03': 20, 'S02E04': 29, 'S02E05': 33, 'S02E06': 42}
from itertools import groupby
out = {}
for key, value in groupby(data, lambda x:x[:3]):
    out[key] = sum([data[val] for val in list(value)])
print (out)
```

Output:

```
{'S01': 188, 'S02': 178}
```